# how to call one action from another in magento?

Tags: magento

is it possible to call one action from another in magento?

for example let us consider 2 action methods

- addAction()
- updateAction()

is it possible to call updateAction() actually when addAction() is called?

Thanks,
Balan

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do a forward, for instance :

```
public function addAction(){
    $this->_forward('update');
}
```

Comment: and is it possible to pass all the params passed to addAction to updateAction?

Comment: @balanv: parameters are passed to the updateAction... if you need custom params you can use the 4th parameter (array of all the custom params), just use null for param 2 and 3 (controller and route are the same)

Comment: is it valid to redirect like $this->_forward('update/id/8'); ?

Comment: I think so, I'm not sure sorry :|

Comment: Aha, more than 1y later :) Hope it helps anyway